# How to print all factorization of an integer in Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, factorization

I am new to programming and trying to learn for loop, nested for loop with if statement.

I have written this code to produce all factorisations of an integer `n`:

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n+1):
    for j in range(0,i):
        if i*j == n:
            print(i,'times',j,'equals',n)
            break
```

now if n=10 it produces the following result:

> 5 times 2 equals 10
>   10 times 1 equals 10

The are couple of problems with this one. First is that it ignores the first factorisation i.e.

> 1 times 10 equals 10

Second problem i want the `i` and `j` to be swapped in result i.e. it should say:

> 1 times 10 equals 10
>   2 times 5 equals 10
>   10 times 1 equals 10

not

> 1 times 10 equals 10
>   5 times 2 equals 10
>   10 times 1 equals 10

Comment: Your desired output doesn't have "5 times 2 equals 10" in it. Any particular reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(0,n+1):
    for j in range(0,i):
```

Here, `j` is in the range `(0,i)`, which means, when `i` is `1`, `j` iterates from `0` to `1`, of course their product won't be `n` when `n` is `10`.

The fix is simple:

```
for i in range(0,n+1):
    for j in range(0,n+1):
```

---

However, the algorithm is pretty slow for big `n`. You don't have to iterate `j` and tests if `i * j == n`, just calculate `j` with `n / i` and tests if it's an integer would do well.

Another optimization is: considering that factors are paired, you only needs to iterate `i` to the square root of `n`, instead of all the way up to `n`.

Comment: this is the code i wrote after your advice. Apparently is also working. Thanks  `n=int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    if n%i==0:
        print(i,'times',str(int(n//i)),'equals',n)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1, int(n / 2) + 1):
    for j in range(1, i):
        if i * j == n:
            print(j, ' times ', i, ' equals ' , n)
```

> Few observations:
>
> - You may not require the break statement if you want to have all the factors
> - There may be duplicates also
> - You may start the loop from 1
> - You may limit the first loop to n/2 as n/2 is the greatest factor less than n
>
> Please take this code as  a starting point and not a copy-paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would like to suggest that you use minimum number of loops and should focus on the efficiency of the code. for example you can do like this:

```
from math import sqrt  #this imports square root from math

n=int(input())
for i in range(1,int(sqrt(n))+1): # this will help in less number of iterations
    if n%i==0:  #checks if n is properly divisible by i or not!
       j=n/i    # if yes then i,j are the factors of n
```

you can now print all the factors or use Break statement when found first factor